# How to match a random number with a number from a list

Tags: python, list, random

I am using a list to keep track of numbers and want to match up the lists index with a random number so I can subtract 1 from the value of that index.

```
import random
race_length = int(input("Choose the Length You Would Like You Race To Be 
(Between 5 and 15)"))
dice = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" ]
cars=[
    ["1", race_length],
    ["2", race_length],
    ["3", race_length],
    ["4", race_length],
    ["5", race_length],
    ["6", race_length],
]
while race_length >0:    
    print("Press Enter to Roll the Dice")
    input()
    chosen = int(random.choice(dice))
    print(int(chosen))
```

What would I do so i can match the chosen match with the numbers in my list

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to match with list simply choose from list

```
import random
race_length = int(input("Choose the Length You Would Like You Race To Be (Between 5 and 15)"))
cars=[
    ["1", race_length],
    ["2", race_length],
    ["3", race_length],
    ["4", race_length],
    ["5", race_length],
    ["6", race_length],
]
while race_length >0:    
    print("Press Enter to Roll the Dice")
    input()
    chosen = random.choice(cars)
    print(chosen[0])
    chosen[1]-=1
```

Also you cast to int way to much. so print(int("1")) would cast "1" to one and than in turn it will be converted to "1" again.

EDIT: Substracting one from the choosen can simply done by substracting one from the choosen field at index 1.

Comment: i need to match them as i need to determine what one to subtract 1 from the race distance

Answer (score 0):

> ...want to match up the lists index with a random number so I can subtract 1 from the value of that index.

You don't need to add indices along with each element in `cars`. Create a normal list:

```
cars = [race_length] * len(dice)
```

and index and subtract as:

```
cars[chosen-1] -= 1
```

**Code**:

```
import random

race_length = int(input("Choose the Length You Would Like You Race To Be (Between 5 and 15)"))
dice = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" ]
cars = [race_length] * len(dice)
while race_length >0:    
    print("Press Enter to Roll the Dice")
    input()
    chosen = int(random.choice(dice))
    print(chosen)
    cars[chosen-1] -= 1
    print(cars)
```

But this is going to infinity and user has to terminate program his own.

Comment: In my actual program I have a way where it will stop, however I would like to change the value of the race length seperatly for all 6 'numbers'

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *"separately"*?

Comment: be able to change the value of the race_length for different indexes like 2 in the list.

Comment: Against infinity: `while min(cars) > 0:`

Comment: He never stated how race_length is reduced. Maybe it is min of all car specific race_lengths